# jogo de forca em C++

Tags: c++, string, jogos

Oi, pessoal. Estou com um problema em relação a uma parte especifica do jogo, que já esta completo. O unico problema é a condição que eu pus para verificar se a palavra foi completamente adivinhada. Meu codigo:

```
if (strchr(palavra,letra[0])!= NULL) {
      ptr =strchr(palavra, letra[0]);

      while(ptr != NULL){
        i = (ptr-palavra);
        ptr = strchr(ptr+1, letra[0]);
        tela[i] = letra[0];
        acert++;
      }

      for(i=0;i<strlen(palavra);i++){
        cout << "\t" << tela[i];
      }
      }
    else {
      cout << "\n\tletra errada.\n";
      max++;
    }
```

O `acert++` conta quantas letras foram acertadas e se o numero de letras for igual ao tamanho da palavra, ele diz que voce venceu.
O problema é que como ele passa por essa condição toda vez que a letra é acertada, se alguem digitar a mesma letra repetidamente, ele conta aquela mesma letra certa mais de uma vez.

Como eu posso dizer que:

Se letra **nao** contida em array que exibe palavra **contar acert++**

OU

Se letra **ja** contida em array que exibe palavra **nao contar acert++**

Acho que o primeiro modo é mais facil de incrementar, só nao sei como. Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: pensando logicamente não seria mais válido uma condição que verifica se a letra repete-se 2 ou 3 vezes seguida, com isso o ```acert++``` se alternaria para ```acert--``` ele remove 1 ou mais acertos, fazendo com o as letras repetidas não sejam contabilizadas como certas.

Comment: Pode ser, mas como eu escrevo essa condição? "condição que verifica se a letra repete-se 2 ou 3 vezes seguida". É essa minha duvida central.

Comment: Cara não sei como resolver em C++, mas oque se pode fazer é criar uma váriavel pra contar quais letras já foram escolhidas e não deixar repetir letra

Comment: @user237530 amigo fica um pouco difícil somente com uma parte do código, teria como disponibiliza-lo por completo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar!

Adicionei isso a condição do loop:

```
verif[0] = '_';

  while(max <= 5 || (strchr(tela, verif[0]) != NULL)){
```

E acrescentei no final:

```
    else if (strchr(tela, verif[0]) == NULL){
      limpar;
      cout << "\n\n\n\tVoce venceu! Palavra Adivinhada: " << palavra << endl;
      break;
    }
```

Ele verifica se ainda tem `_`  na palavra e se ela tiver sido completamente adivinhada (ou seja, só tiver letras e nenhum _ ), ele para.